# How to write belongs to symbol in latex

Tags: symbols

I want to write this belongs to symbol in latex like this

x belongs to R^M. that you normally see in papers. Suggestions?

Comment: `\in`? [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Comment: `\usepackage{amssymb}` and then `x \in \mathbb{R}^{M}` in math mode, of course.